# oracle varchar to number

Tags: oracle, numbers, varchar

How do i convert a oracle varchar value to number

eg

```
table - exception
exception_value 555 where exception_value is a varchar type
```

I would like to test the value of exception_value column

```
select * from exception where exception_value = 105 instead of
select * from exception where exception_value = '105'
```

Answer (score 43):

You have to use the [TO_NUMBER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm#i79512) function:

```
select * from exception where exception_value = to_number('105')
```

Answer (score 13):

Since the column is of type VARCHAR, you should convert the input parameter to a string rather than converting the column value to a number:

```
select * from exception where exception_value = to_char(105);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want formated number then use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(number, 'fmt')
   FROM DUAL;

SELECT TO_CHAR('123', 999.99)
   FROM DUAL;
```

Result
123.00

Answer (score 3):

I have tested the suggested solutions, they should all work:

```
select * from dual where (105 = to_number('105'))
```

=> delivers one dummy row

```
select * from dual where (10 = to_number('105'))
```

=> empty result

```
select * from dual where ('105' = to_char(105))
```

=> delivers one dummy row

```
select * from dual where ('105' = to_char(10))
```

=> empty result

Answer (score 1):

select to_number(exception_value) from exception where to_number(exception_value) = 105