# Check if a varchar is a number in Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

How Do I check if a varchar is a number or contains any special characters in Oracle forms.

I tried using the below code but its giving me logical error

```
declare
    v_valid varchar2(15);
begin
    v_valid := :HEADERS.REFERENCE ;
If NOT v_valid IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') then
        message('Characters or Special Symbols are not allowed here');
end if; 
end;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154612/oracle-varchar-to-number there is a post on it.

Answer (score 4):

Try convert it to a number and catch the exception.

```
    vVarchar varchar2(15) := '15';
    nNumber number;
    BEGIN
        nNumber := to_number(vVarchar);         
        message('Success!!');
    EXCEPTION WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        message('Characters or Special Symbols are not allowed here');
    END;
```

<strike>This is actually what you are doing</strike> with `If v_valid NOT Between '0' AND '9' then` you will get a lot of problems with input like this: `'2aas', '9&%$'`

Consider changing `:HEADERS.REFERENCE` to number in the properties of the object, should be easier.

Comment: This is (almost) the way I should do this but I do not recommend you to use the WHEN OTHERS. Instead use the number of the oracle exception you get when you try to convert a number to string. This should be 6502 if I remember correct.

Comment: @PeterÅkerlund Edited accordingly, let me know if that is correct, or should I put `EXCEPTION WHEN 6502`?? I don't know how to use the oracle code in this, I've always used the word.

Comment: You could replace the VALUE_ERROR with the number but I don't see any need for that. Your way is much better coding practice.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it. Here is the code

```
declare
    v_valid varchar2(15);
begin
    v_valid := :HEADERS.REFERENCE ;
If v_valid NOT Between '0' AND '9' then
        message('Characters or Special Symbols are not allowed here');
end if; 
end;
```

Comment: You will have a lot of issues that way. Note that `'2A' IS INDEED BETWEEN '0' and '9'`

Comment: This will only work properly if you have only one digit in your string. The best way is to try to convert it to an number and trap the error.

Comment: This is a completely unacceptable solution based on prior comments, please mark Roger's answer correct.