# use string value like numeric value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a condition in my oracle query:

```
AND a.ACCARDACNT > '0880080200000006' and a.ACCARDACNT < '0880080200001000'
```

type of ACCARDACNT column in table is `varchar` and indexed but in that condition I want to use it as number. When I execute this query, the execution plan shows that CBO can use index and scan the table by index.
is it true?

I want to use and compare them  as number and also an indexed be used. Is there any solution?

Comment: I think an index can be used, but keep in mind that the comparison you are making is against _text_, and not a number.  Your sorting might not always behave the way you expect.

Comment: I want to use and compare them  as number and also an index be used. is there any solution?

Comment: If the execution plans shows that Oracle uses an index, the it will (almost always) use an index - so what exactly is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicated. Use TO_NUMBER function. Your solution maybe is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154612/oracle-varchar-to-number

Comment: So, are **all** the values in ACCARDACNT numerics?

Comment: Are all numbers in `ACCARDACNT` stored with exactly 16 digits?

Comment: @APC yes but the column is foreign key of so many tabled and change its type is impossible

Comment: @ThorstenKettner no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query should be able to use an index.  But the problem is that you are comaparing text but expecting it to sort numerically.  It may not, in general, because text sorts lexicographically in SQL (i.e. in dictionary order).  So, to get the correct sorting behavior you will have to cast `ACCARDACNT` to a number:

```
AND CAST(LTRIM(a.ACCARDACNT, '0') AS FLOAT) BETWEEN 880080200000007 AND 880080200000999
```

Comment: @Mahsaehsani Try casting directly to float.

Comment: Then I think your data has a problem.

Comment: *"Still has error : invalid number"* - then maybe you were mistaken when you asserted just now that all the values of ACCARDACNT are numerics.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes . your right . i correct them and now my query execute correctly . Thanks

Comment: 1) Trimming leading zeros is superfluous. 2) `FLOAT` is not an exact type. I guess it works here, but I recommend avoiding floats in a DBMS. 3) In case there are not only integers, but also decimal numbers, the stored decimal separator (`.` or `,`) must match the current session setting. 4) The existing index will not be used anymore. I'd recommend providing a function index for that.

Answer (score 3):

If it is guaranteed that all `ACCARDACNT` are numbers, then just use

```
and to_number(a.accardacnt) > 880080200000006 and a.accardacnt < 880080200001000;
```

This makes sure that the numbers are no compared as strings where `'2' > '10'`, because looking at the first characters '2' is greater than '1'.

(In case of decimal numbers, make sure that the the decimal separator stored in the strings matches the current session settings.)

If you want to provide an index for this, use this function index:

```
create index idx_accardacnt on mytable( to_number(accardacnt) );
```

or a composite index containing `to_number(accardacnt)`. As the execution plan for the strings query showed an index to be used, the same should be true for the numeric comparision and function index. (Remember a DBMS is free to use the provided indexes or not. We are simply offering them, but the DBMS knows best whether it makes sense to use them in a query or not.)

Comment: *"the DBMS knows best"* Actually the optimizer is not always cleverer than us but it's certainly the way to bet :)

Answer (score 1):

Think you cannot use numeric comparison and index together.

> the execution plan shows that CBO can use index

There is a chance that Full Index Scan is used here, so it just a table scan but with less columns.

Possible approach is to convert numbers to fixed length strings with leading zeros and then use ones in comparison. In this case the index will be used.

Comment: That is a good answer. Yes, in case of a full index scan that index can still be used. And making all numbers the same format / length also provides a good workaround for the unfortunate data model. (One could even provide a before-insert/update trigger that does that, or at least provide a check constraint to ensure it.) One thing though: Oracle features function indexes, so you *can* convert the strings to numbers in a query and still use an index. Please see my answer on this.

Comment: was thinking about functional index as well

Answer (score 0):

Another option still would be a computed column:

```
alter table mytable add accardacnt_num as (to_number(accardacnt));
```

and provide one or more indexes containing this column:

```
create index idx_accardacnt_num on mytable(accardacnt_num);
```

Then existing code continues working, but new queries can benefit from the numeric column:

```
and a.accardacnt_num > 880080200000006 and a.accardacnt_num < 880080200001000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following logic does what you might really want:

```
a.ACCARDACNT > '0880080200000006' and
a.ACCARDACNT < '0880080200001000' and
length(ACCARDACNT) = 16
```

In addition, this can use an index on the column, if an appropriate one is available.

This would not be correct if you wanted the 15-character account number `'880080200000060'` to match your criteria.  My guess is that you do not want this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function index on column : `accardacnt` and

```
create index idx_fn_accardant on table_name( to_number(accardacnt) );
```

convert it into number in the where clause of the query query :

```
where to_number(ACCARDACNT) > 0880080200000006 and to_number(ACCARDACNT) < 0880080200001000
```